# I already have a form created in HTML, how can I post the data from this form to the user's account on the Django database?

Tags: django

I am working on the project in which one user can create a quiz on the HTML pages without coding, in an interactive way. This created quiz should be displayed on the screen of another user, who will be attempting the tests. I am using Django framework for backend and I am very new to backend.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is far too broad to get an answer here. You need to make a first attempt, and come back here if you get stuck with a specific implementation detail. Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask for general guidance on how to implement a whole project.

Comment: Yeah, I am working on it. I apologize for this kind of question, this is my first time asking it on Stack Overflow.